# ListView Will Not scroll vertically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

For the life of me I cannot figure out why my ListView will not Scroll Vertically. It works perfectly if I want to scroll Horizontally which is something I do not want. Anyhow, any suggestions?!

And yes I did scavenge the internet...nothing works sadly.

```
<Grid Background="#FF6A6A6A">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="130*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="489" Margin="3,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="897" Background="White" Grid.Column="1">


        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="43" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="877">

            <TextBlock x:Name="Job" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="33" Width="147">
                <Run Text="Job = "></Run>
                <Run Text="{Binding Path= JobNum, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Style" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="162,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="33" Width="185">
                <Run Text="Style = "></Run>
                <Run Text="{Binding Path= Style, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Run>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Due" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="352,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="33" Width="186">
                <Run Text="Due = "></Run>
                <Run Text="{Binding Path= Date, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Run>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Core" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="543,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="33" Width="144">
                 <Run Text="Core = "></Run>
                <Run Text="{Binding Path= Core, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Run>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Tank" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="692,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="33" Width="174">
                 <Run Text="Tank = "></Run>
                <Run Text="{Binding Path= Tank, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Run>
            </TextBlock>
        </Grid>


       <Grid>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding BindCollection}" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  Height="120" Margin="24,10,132,155" Visibility="Visible" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top"  Height="auto"  Margin="10,0,0,0">
                            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Collection}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
       </Grid>
     </Grid>
        <!--<TextBox x:Name="DataTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsReadOnly="True" Height="437" Margin="10,43,0,9" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=ReportText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="877" FontSize="14" TextChanged="DataTextBox_TextChanged" Visibility="Hidden"/>-->


    <Button x:Name="Close" Content="Close" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="334,544,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="99" Height="33" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
    <Button x:Name="Print" Content="Print" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="458,544,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="99" Height="33" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <GroupBox Grid.Column="1" Header="Print" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="579,523,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="73" Width="129" Foreground="White">
        <StackPanel>
            <RadioButton x:Name="Portrait" IsChecked="True" Foreground="White">Portrait</RadioButton>
            <RadioButton x:Name="Landscape" Foreground="White">Landscape</RadioButton>
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>

</Grid>
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to WPF so maybe I'm way off, but...  It seems to me that if you set the ListView's VerticalAlignment to "Stretch", it's always going to fit the ListView within the space allotted to it. There would never be a reason to scroll. So I recommend removing the VerticalAlignment property or change it to some non-fitting behavior.

Comment: What is the parent container of the `Grid` containing the `ListView`?  It would help to see the entire subtree from the root element down to your `ListView`.

Comment: Updated my question with all the Xaml involved

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.  I copied your entire XAML subtree into a test project, and the vertical scroll bar switches on once the number of items hits 8 or so.  Does the scroll bar remain disabled for you?  Or can you drag the scroll bar, and the content just doesn't appear to scroll?

Comment: @MikeStrobel The scroll bar is visible but it is disabled for some reason.

Comment: And the items inside the `ListView` are visible?  How many items fit in the viewport?

Comment: @MikeStrobel Yes, the items inside the ListView are visible. The ListView is being populated with 25 items and are all view able if I increase the height of the ListView. Strange, I was able to put "Dummy" Data into ListView and it was able to scroll up and down. The hell?!

Comment: Any chance you're using a custom `ListView` style/template?  Everything works as expected if I drop your XAML into an empty project.

Comment: @MikeStrobel No not using any special style/template or anything fancy like that. Hmm, I think I know what the deal is. The Xaml is fine, but I believe that my ViewModel is the culprit in this situation. Il report back soon.

Comment: you may try to remove `HorizontalAlignment="Left"` from the Grid controls and see if that helps.

Comment: Fixed the Issue! My Xaml was fine, but the backend code was jacking everything up. Ended up throwing the data into an Observable Collection which for some reason fixed everything. THANKS ALL!! Case Closed. *Makes a gentle nod at the computer screen*